# How to say if any object in a list is in another list return true in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example I want the out put here to be true because 1 is in the second list

```
[1,2,3] in ['a', 'b', 'c', 1]
```

I want like if any object from the first list is in the second list then return true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `any` (which outputs `True` if any element in a list is `True`) with a generator expression:

```
any(i in ['a', 'b', 'c', 1] for i in [1,2,3])
```

Comment: replace outer `[...]` with `(...)` in order not to create a needless intermediate list

Comment: Good point, thanks!